# ManagedOpenSsl in .net core throws "System.BadImageFormatException:"

Tags: c#, .net-core, openssl-net

I have been facing multiple challenges with getting the ManagedOpenSsl to work with .Net Core. I downloaded ManagedOpenSsl.NetCore from nuget package.

My End Goal is to create a .pfx file from certificate PEM and private key. In the below code, `ocert.KeyPair.PrivateKey` is the certificate private key and `ocert.CertificatePem` is the certificate PEM.

```
ManagedOpenSsl.NetCore.Core.BIO key_bio = new ManagedOpenSsl.NetCore.Core.BIO(ocert.KeyPair.PrivateKey);
            ManagedOpenSsl.NetCore.Core.BIO cert_bio = new ManagedOpenSsl.NetCore.Core.BIO(ocert.CertificatePem);

            ManagedOpenSsl.NetCore.Crypto.CryptoKey key = ManagedOpenSsl.NetCore.Crypto.CryptoKey.FromPrivateKey(ocert.KeyPair.PrivateKey, "xxxxx");
            ManagedOpenSsl.NetCore.X509.X509Certificate cert = new ManagedOpenSsl.NetCore.X509.X509Certificate(cert_bio);
            ManagedOpenSsl.NetCore.Core.Stack<ManagedOpenSsl.NetCore.X509.X509Certificate> hmm = new ManagedOpenSsl.NetCore.Core.Stack<ManagedOpenSsl.NetCore.X509.X509Certificate>();

            var pfx = new ManagedOpenSsl.NetCore.X509.PKCS12(password, key, cert, hmm); // <-- 
            ManagedOpenSsl.NetCore.X509.X509Certificate certpfx = pfx.Certificate;
```

I'm getting error

> {System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'ManagedOpenSsl.NetCore.Core.Native' threw an exception. --->
>   System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program
>   with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)   at
>   ManagedOpenSsl.NetCore.Core.Native.SSLeay()   at
>   ManagedOpenSsl.NetCore.Core.Version.get_Library()   at
>   ManagedOpenSsl.NetCore.Core.Native..cctor()   --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace - in the line of code
>   `ManagedOpenSsl.NetCore.Core.BIO key_bio = new
>   ManagedOpenSsl.NetCore.Core.BIO(ocert.KeyPair.PrivateKey);

In Visual Studio 2017 project properties , I have set the Platform Target to "Any CPU", still the issue occurs. Also any implementation on how to save the `pfx.Certificate` to a specific folder in .pfx format ? Any help will be appreciated. Been struggling with this issue for a while now.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is unmanaged code, you need to be specific about the bitness.  Do not target "Any CPU". Compile you project for the bitness of target program. If you will be using it on both x86 and x64 processes, compile into 2 different binaries.

Comment: I resolved this issue using Chilkat Dotnet core library.